# Making a Call by Image icon in a List view by fragments in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a list view with person picture, name and image icon for calling.
I passed the picture and name by arrays but gives errors when passing phone numbers as a array.

**Arrays**

```
String[] names = {"abc", "xyz"}
int [] pics = {getting 2 images from drawable};
String[] phone_numbers = {"0110101010","0110101010"};
```

**My code**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_list, container,false);


studentList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.studentListView);

//adapter object set list view to it
studentListAdapter madapter = new studentListAdapter (getActivity(),names,pics); 

//calling function
studentList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(phone_numbers));

    }

});
```

Edit: My error is when `Uri.parse(phone_numbers));` shows error. `String phone_numbers = "0110101010"` correct the error(removing as a array). But it does not the solution I want.

Please help me to launch call from list items.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: and show your adapter code

Comment: Have you added one more parameter in ShopInfoAdapter class constructor of type String[]  to receive phone number?

Comment: @VivekMishra please check the edit in my question.

Comment: you can't pass complete array in that method add a single number in Uri.parse() method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Passing complete array of phone numbers to `Uri.parse()` method, pass a single number from your array to that method.

Like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(phone_numbers[0]));
```

Comment: by adding this shows unfortunatly stopped error. help me on this. @VivekMishra

Comment: add your crash logs and line on which it crashes in your question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_list, container,false);


    studentList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.studentListView);

    //adapter object set list view to it
    studentListAdapter madapter = new studentListAdapter (getActivity(),names,pics); 

    //calling function
    studentList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_numbers[targetposition]));
startActivity(intent);   


        }

    });
```

EDIT:
i edited the code above, also make sure to include this in your androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: by adding this shows unfortunatly stopped error. help me on this. @locomain,